# APPFOG error logs for Grails

Tags: grails, appfog

I am getting some errors in my Grails in in AppFog, but I am not sure how to get to the bottom if it.

```
C:\Users\me>af logs myapp
[WARNING] DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Error (JSON 404): Not Found


C:\Users\me>af crashes myapp
[WARNING] DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Error (JSON 404): Not Found
```

I read this could help, but I am not sure where to put it?

```
app.debug = True
```

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot please?

Answer (score 0):

Tried the commands again, this time from Linux.  Worked perfect.

Note: AF from Windows does not work very well.